# two column mode break and open two column again

Tags: two-column, cuted

I have using `\twocolumn` command for 2 column mode. In the end of paper (before `thebibliography`) i would like to close `\twocolumn` mode (for the base aligning text). Afterthat, i will open `\begin{thebibliography}` should come in `two column` mode. How to get the output.

I would expect the below output:

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,amsmath}
\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{cuted}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{widetext}%\twocolumn
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{widetext}

\begin{strip}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{strip}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

with multicols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,amsmath}
%\usepackage{widetext}
%\usepackage{flushend}
%\usepackage{cuted}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}%\twocolumn
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I don'i have others packages.